# Select all ids of friends of current user?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Here is the structure of my tables:

First table "users":

```
id  --  email  --    name  
1  --   example  --  John  
2  --   example2 --  Paul
3  --   example3 --  Sara
```

users table stores all users with its emails

Second table "friends":

```
id --   id_from --  id_to  
1  --     1    --     2  
2  --     1    --     3  
3  --     2    --     3
```

friends table stores friendship between users for example John(id:1) is friend with Paul(id:2) and Sara(id:3)

My Question is how can I get all friends of John. I can get one friend by this line of code:

```
$stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id_from = ? OR id_to = ?");
```

but I need to get all friends of particular user

Comment: That query will select all, 2 rows in your example.

Comment: @AbraCadaver but in that case I need to insert id_to I need some code similar to

Comment: @AbraCadaver  $stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE id_from = ? ");

Comment: @ For example if I insert 1 to the id_from it will give me the list of friends which has the id_from = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$stmt = $this->prepare("
    SELECT u.*
    FROM users u
    JOIN friends f ON u.id = f.id_to
    WHERE f.id_from = ?
    UNION
    SELECT u.*
    FROM users u
    JOIN friends f ON u.id = f.id_from
    WHERE f.id_to = ?
");
```

Comment: I get "Call to undefined method DbOperations::prepare()" this error when I want to test it from postman

Comment: I used the same function you wrote in your question.

Comment: @ RadicalDingos  and did that help you

Answer (score 1):

you can use `exists` to check for the friends of the user with `id = 1`:

```
select * from users u
where exists (
  select 1 from friends f
  where 
  (f.id_from = 1 and f.id_to = u.id) 
  or
  (f.id_to = 1 and f.id_from = u.id)
)
```

or if you just need the ids of the friends:

```
select id_to friendid from friends where id_from = 1 and id_to is not null
union
select id_from friendid from friends where id_to = 1 and id_from is not null
```

Comment: could you possible explain more briefly coz I'm new to php I'm using it only to integrate with android

Comment: This is not php, it's just the sql statement to use in your php code.

Comment: it gives me:  {
    "error": false,
    "friends": {
        "id_to": null,
        "id_from": null
    }
}

Comment: These sql statements fetches ids, regardless if they are null or not, although I don't believe you have null values inside friends table, do you?. The error does not come from the statement. it is a php related error.

Comment: yeah i have values in my friends table

Comment: You mean **null** values in id_from or id_to columns?

Comment: Here is my dboperation.ph:

Comment: public function getMyFriend(){
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id_to friendid from friends WHERE id_from = ? UNION 
                SELECT id_from friendid from friends WHERE id_to = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_from, $id_to);
            $stmt->execute(); 
            $stmt->bind_result($id_to, $id_from);
            $stmt->fetch(); 
            $friend = array(); 
            $friend['id_to'] = $id_to; 
            $friend['id_from']=$id_from; 
            return $friend; 
        }

Comment: and in my index.php i run this code: app->get('/friendget', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $db = new DbOperations; 
    $friends = $db->getMyFriend($id_from, $id_to);
    $response_data = array();
    $response_data['error'] = false; 
    $response_data['friends'] = $friends; 
    $response->write(json_encode($response_data));
    return $response
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
    ->withStatus(200);  
});

Comment: I edited the code on the union statement to reject any null values, but for the php code I can't help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186729/discussion-between-white-and-forpas).